# Cannot Create Azure AKS Namespace with Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Admin role

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-rbac

I've deployed an Azure Kubernetes Service with the **Azure AD authentication with Azure RBAC** Authentication mode configured.

I have given myself the

- `Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role`
- `Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Admin`

- roles.

And with this I can:

- List deployments
- Create deployments
- Tear down deployments

Across all namespaces.

However neither of these allow me to create a `namespace`, and from what I can tell no obvious other roles touch on this permission.

For example `kubectl create namespace test-namespace` Raises:

```bash
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "USER AZURE AD" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope: User does not have access to the resource in Azure. Update role assignment to allow access.
```

I am aware that pulling credentials with `az aks get-credentials -g {Resource Group} --name {CLUSTER NAME} --admin` is a workaround, but this particular cluster cannot have `Kubertnetes local accounts` enabled so this is not an option.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, create one **custom RBAC role** with **`Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/namespaces/write`** permission under your subscription:

[image]

Clone a role with Azure `Kubernetes service RBAC Admin`:

[image]

In permission tab you can find **NotDataActions** remove the `Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/namespaces/write` from `NotDataActions` and add the same permission:

[image]

[image]

Once the custom role is created, now assign the role assignment:

[image]

When I run the namespace command got desired output:

`kubectl create namespace test-namespace`

[**Output**](https://i.imgur.com/px7whaJ.png)

***Reference***: [Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#azure-kubernetes-service-rbac-admin)